# Single Selection item with Recycler Grid View

Tags: android, gridview

I have an issue, i am selecting a single item at a time with `Recycler Gridview`, when I click on another item last item should be unselected

Comment: kindly share your code

Comment: can you use model class for items ? if yes then show it

Comment: No i am not using the model class @Niceumang

Comment: then you can handle this using boolean flag i means handle it with true and false value

Comment: If possible then using model class its too easy for handling !

Comment: It would be appreciated if you share a sample code.

Comment: hi @sandeep Sharma, I suggest you to use a flag as a boolean, return true if the item is clicked else false..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for your requirement

```
public class AdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterClass.ViewHolder> {
        private int selected_position = -1;

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterClass.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            if (selected_position == position) {
                // do your stuff here like
                //Change selected item background color and Show sub item views

            } else {
                  // do your stuff here like
                  //Change  unselected item background color and Hide sub item views
            }
  // rest of the code here

    holder.linelayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              if(selected_position==position){
                        selected_position=-1;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        return;
                    }
                    selected_position = position;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

    //rest of the code here

     }


}
```

Comment: Thanks , it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

create a variable:

```
private var lastSub: View? = null
```

and on your onClickListener of the recyclerview item use like this:

```
override fun onClick(view: View) {
   //val subjects = view.tag as Subject
   //subId = subjects.id
   if (lastSub != view && lastSub != null) {
     lastSub!!.background = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.color.white, null)
     view.background = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.card_border, null)
     lastSub = view
   } else {
     view.background = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.card_border, null)
     lastSub = view
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            class AdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterClass.ViewHolder> {
             private int currentPosition = -1;
                private int previousPosition = -1;
             @Override
                public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterClass.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.currentPos = position;


            if(currentPosition == -1) {
                    previousPosition = position;
                } else {

                }
            } else {
                if(previousPosition == position) {

                }
                if(currentPosition == position) {
                    previousPosition = currentPosition;
                } else {

                }
            }
        }
            }

// in view holder onClick you can notify previous and current
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    notifyItemChanged(previousPosition);
                    currentPosition = currentPos;
                    notifyItemChanged(currentPosition);
                }
```